# Wrong value return by val

Tags: javascript, html

I make a JQueryUI slider and i send his value to an hidden input.
I retrieve the value by using .val(); and change it into an integer.
But! The span haven't the same value of the input.

Here is my Fiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/d488c3ja/

Maybe the problem is the `parseInt();`

Comment: You should change the order of `$("#jdhXj").val(ui.value)` and `jkFuncx();`: https://jsfiddle.net/fmhLpowc/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call the function after the value initiated like

```
   $(function() {
     $("#slider").slider({
range: "min",
value: 1,
min: 1,
max: 10,
slide: function(event, ui) {
  //jkFuncx(); you have called the function here
  $("#jdhXj").val(ui.value)
  jkFuncx();
}
```